# How to store File in storage and make that read only? How to set the permission of File?

Tags: android

How to store `File` in storage and make that read only? How to set the permission of `File`?

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/AFolder");
if (!folder.exists()) {
    folder.mkdir();
    Log.e(String.valueOf(folder),"Created......" );
}
bval = folder.setReadOnly();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797746/android-read-write-permission-of-a-folder

Comment: `folder.mkdir();`. Check the return value. Do not just suppose and say that it is created.

Comment: What is wrong with `folder.setReadOnly();` ?

Comment: Java has AFAIK no good working API for changing file/directory permissions. For changing file permissions you have to call `chmod`/`chgrp`.